# How to extract a value from JSON that repeats multiple times?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to create a select that returns me something like this:

[image]

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT Code, json_extract_path(Registers::json,'sales', 'name') 
FROM tbl_registers
```

The previous code returns me a NULL in json_extract_path, I have tried the operator `::json->'sales'->>'name'`, but doesn't work too.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) so people trying to help you can easily copy and paste the data. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PGAdmin is version 4 and Postgres: "PostgreSQL 9.5.15"

Comment: @eshirvana The expected output tis the second table. 2 columns with Code and Products.

Comment: Also unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, and the aggregate the names back. This can be done using `json_array_elements` with a scalar sub-query:

```
select code, 
       (select string_agg(e ->> 'name', ',')
        from json_array_elements(t.products) as x(e)) as products
from tbl_registers t;
```

I would also strongly recommend to change your column's type to `jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d2e28a1aa3d84ef230b9a7f0b91b240)

```
SELECT
    code,
    string_agg(                                     -- 3
         elems ->> 'name',                          -- 2
         ','
    ) as products
FROM tbl_registers,
    json_array_elements(products::json) as elems    -- 1
GROUP BY code
```

1. If you have type text (strictly not recommended, please use appropriate data type `json` or `jsonb`), then you need to cast it into type `json` (I guess you have type text because you do the cast already in your example code). Afterwards you need to extract the array elements into one row per element
2. Fetch the `name` value
3. Reaggregate by grouping and use `string_agg()` to create the string list